# SSL connection difference between Android and Windows Phone

Tags: android, ssl, https, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have some experience in working with `Android`. In this OS in order to create `SSL` connection with a website I can create `BKS` file then I can load this file into my `HTTPSHandler`, and using this handler allows me to contacting with website through `HTTPS` protocol.

This way I do not import the `certificate` file directly to my `OS` Keystore but instead I allow my application for using this.

And here is my actual question because I am just learning how to create apps for `WP8`. Is there similar possibility in this `OS`? I have found information that in order to create `HTTPS` connections I have to use `Defoult Handler` after manual installing of `Public Key` in format of `.cert` on the device.

Is there no way to use it like `android`? I would like to avoid installing certificates in `Operating System` keystore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to use a cert within your application without installing it on the device.